# Cloud9 ide img not working

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, cloud9-ide

I can use background img tags still but cloud 9 is not displaying images for me. I have used local and online images to try and nothing. Also if it helps I'm using bootstrap. I have been able to use images before fyi.

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , and reformulate your question... If you're not more explicite, your question will be closed. If a man says "my car doesn't work", it may have a lot of reasons.

Comment: Can you paste some html with the part of the code that contains the images?

Comment: It's not my html code. I switched back to notepad++ and the code works perfectly. I believe it's a cloud9 settings or error. I know my question is general but my situation is general. I just love the live preview in cloud9 not refreshing every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`<img src="/images/example.png"></img>`
or 
`<img src="~/images/example.png"></img>`

try using source path with foldername or filename directly like this

`<img src="images/example.png"></img>`